# Cant access tables of Hive from jdbc hive client(HIVESERVER2)

Tags: hive, bigdata

I have created some databases in Hive .After that I configured Hiveserver2 with jdbc client.
but through jdbc client i cant  see hive databases, I can see only those databases which i created through jdbc client in hiveserver.
need your help

Answer (score 1):

You can check below points :

Check1:Check the metastore and database ,you have provided in hive-site.xml
Check2:Check by providing the correct privileges to you metastore db. like below:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'root'@'%'
CREATE USER 'hive'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'hive';
GRANT all on *.* to 'hive'@localhost identified by 'hive';
flush privileges;
```

Let me know if it solves your problem..